# No way to debug iOS issues in web apps from Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, safari

I've found a few bugs while testing a web app on an iPad Pro and iPhone 7 Plus that I can't replicate with any browser in Windows or Android and I cannot find any way to remote debug Safari in Windows.

I tried using [RemoteDebug iOS WebKit Adapter](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter) but the devices don't appear to be discoverable with either the Chrome or VS Code debuggers.

I've confirmed that Web Inspector is enabled in Safari, the device is discoverable and trusted using iTunes, and that all necessary/recommended dependencies are installed. The server starts fine, there are just no devices listed in the debuggers.

Some searching through replies to previously submitted questions suggests that this has been broken for versions of iOS > 11 but the latest commit to that repo suggests support for iOS 12.2+ has been added as of January 2 of this year. (I'm trying to debug the app for iOS 13.3)

I'm curious if anyone else has run into this and have found any workarounds for debugging iOS specific issues using a Windows PC. Or if there are good alternate solutions (short of buying a Mac) if not.

Comment: same issue. did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 19):

The creator of `remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter` here. I've built a replacement for `RemoteDebug` called [Inspect](http://inspect.dev/), which packages everything together in a pleasant experience and enables easy iOS web debugging from Windows, macOS, and Linux, with a few extra features like screen-casting and Wi-Fi debugging, that you might find useful.

Comment: A helpful answer, and important to note the replacement is commercial with a 30 day free trial. "Inspect is an independent venture, and we think great developer tools should cost money."

Comment: I do agree with Doug about great developer tools should cost money, if the developer used only his knowledge to built it. But if the developer used other developers to test his code as beta testers (guinea pigs) the code is not proprietary but collective, which seems to be the case of this. Specially when the "Archived" code was funded by Microsoft.

Comment: So is the simple answer to this that, yes, there is no way in 2021 to remote debug iOS Safari just using the tools I already have or can download for free? I don't disagree with paying for your work in principle, I'm just surprised neither Apple nor Microsoft makes this available with all the other tools they give developers to get them on their platforms.

Comment: Seems to work as advertised with iOS 15.2.1 and Windows 10; 14 day trial now. Requires iTunes installed on Windows.

Answer (score 11):

[Followed the steps described by John Washam](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/#:%7E:text=Open%20up%20the%20Chrome%20browser,chrome%3A%2F%2Finspect%2F%23devices.&text=Enable%20web%20inspector%20on%20your,and%20browse%20to%20a%20website). I did tried this yesterday (iPAD Pro with iOS 14 and Windows 10) and I can confirm that it works.

Here to summarize the solution for remote debugging iOS devices > iOS 11:

1. Install [iTunes](https://www.apple.com/itunes/download) on your Windows 10 PC.
2. Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).
3. [Download the most recent ZIP release file](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/releases) of the `remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter`
4. Create a new folder named "ios-webkit-debug-proxy-1.8.8-win64-bin" at the following location (assumes you installed Node.js in the default directory):

   ```
   %AppData%\npm\node_modules\remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter\node_modules\vs-libimobile\
   ```
5. Extract the files from the ZIP to that folder:

   ```
   %AppData%\npm\node_modules\remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter\node_modules\vs-libimobile\ios-webkit-debug-proxy-1.8.8-win64-bin
   ```

   --> *The folder `vs-libimobile` was missing in my case thus I simply created it*.
6. Edit the `iosAdapter.js` file. Open the file from the following location
   `%AppData%\npm\node_modules\remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter\out\adapters\iosAdapter.js`. On line 125ff., change the proxy variable to the following value (path to the `ois_webkit_debug_proxy.exe`):

   ```js
   const proxy = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/vs-libimobile/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-1.8.8-win64-bin/ios_webkit_debug_proxy.exe');
   ```
7. Go to `%AppData%\npm`, open PowerShell and type in the following command:

   ```
   .\remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter --port=9000
   ```
8. Open up Chrome on your Win PC and browse to `chrome://inspect/#devices`.

   Since we set the adapter to listen on port 9000, we need to add a network target. Click “Configure” next to Discover network targets:
9. Enable web inspector on your iOS device.
   Take your iOS device and go to `Settings > Safari > Advanced` and enable Web Inspector.
10. Open Safari on your iOS device and browse to a website.
    You should almost immediately see the website appear in Chrome under the Remote Target section.

Comment: some corrections: step 7 -> line 132 not '125ff', step 8 -> no need to Go to %AppData%\npm

Comment: When I run the command `.\remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter --port=9000` I have error:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at Request._callback (C:\Users\pp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter\out\adapters\iosAdapter.js:44:38) at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\pp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22) at Request.emit (events.js:210:5) at Request.<anonymous>`...

Comment: Ok it seems that it working fine under the different port: `.\remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter --port=9222`

Comment: Firstly, thank you. This does work, although, like others, I had to use a different port.

However, it is extremely buggy. It barely works, and most actions cause it to crash and disconnect. This is the case in any Chromium-based browser I've tried,m and on two different Windows PCs.

Perhaps it just doesn't work that well anymore on Windows 11 and with newer versions of iOS.

Any insight from others would be really helpful; Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

After many hours googling and trying to get iTunes to recognize the phone (needed driver update from Windows update), and then trying to get to work with `remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter` since it doesn't work properly for iOS 13+ and breaks when inspecting styles or objects, found [`ios-safari-remote-debug-kit`](https://github.com/HimbeersaftLP/ios-safari-remote-debug-kit) which worked correctly on Windows 10 machine to debug a webpage running on an iPhone 7 with iOS 15.4.

Additional steps: For me, the Python webserver didn't work, so had to remove the condition at line 46 of start.ps1 script to just use the NodeJS one.

Update: Installing Python3 from Windows Store fixed Python server issue.

Comment: I had this issue. Worked with nodejs and not python. My issue was the Windows Store link overriding my python in the env path.

The script contains Get-Command "python3.exe".
Running the returned  source path form that in PS opened the windows store, even though I already have python installed on my path.

To disable in Windows 11:
Settings > Apps > Advanced app settings > App execution aliases.
Look for the entries labelled:
App Installer
python3.exe

also python.exe as well. Update start.ps1 if your system uses python.exe instead of python3.exe

Comment: For future readers: I fixed this bug, it will now detect whether Python is actually installed or just the Store shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

With [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) you can install a webkit browser that behaves almost the same as Safari desktop to debug your CSS issues.

[Here's an article that explains step by step how to install a webkit browser in Windows](https://blog.codeisc.com/2022/03/11/safari-webkit-wsl2-windows10-windows11.html)